# Python/PySide limit refresh rate of Model/View

Tags: python, performance, user-interface, pyside

I have a Model like this:

```
class GeneralAssetIconModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GeneralAssetIconModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._data = []

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self._data)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
            taskModel = self._data[index.row()]
            ext = taskModel.getData().obj['type']['ext']

            pix = QtGui.QPixmap(160, 160)
            pix.load('Assets/thumbnail-default.jpg')

            if ext == '.ma':
                pass
            if ext == '.psd':
                pix = PhotoshopHelper.getLatestThumbnail(taskModel)
            if ext == '.ai':
                pix = IllustratorHelper.getLatestThumbnail(taskModel)
            if ext == '.mra':
                pix = MariHelper.getLatestThumbnail(taskModel)
            if ext == '.indd':
                pix = IndesignHelper.getLatestThumbnail(taskModel)
```

The issue I'm having is that "getLatestThumbnail" function always reads thumbnail data from a server file and tries to display it in the view and this operation is quite slow. And when I have 30 or more items displayed in the list the whole thing becomes really slow and laggy.

Is there a way to limit the amount of times the view requests data from the model?

Comment: I would suggest you instead modify the Helper classes so that they locally cache thumbnails.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but limiting refresh would be an easy way out. Maybe just refresh it once on initial load of the items. But I don't know how to control the behaviour. @three_pineapples

Comment: Does the thumbnails change really often ? If not, you could store them locally and have a method to update them when needed. To avoid any lag, you could put this update method in a separate thread.

Comment: As I said, I could create a system that makes local cache of server thumbnails, but that takes some time to implement. For now it would be perfect if I could make it so the list item requests a thumbnail only once on initial load. @tmoreau

Comment: How often is `if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:` entered?

Comment: A lot of times. Basically ~10-20 times a second when you hover over it with a mouse. It has some kind of internal event system that triggers the data method of the model to be called. And this is done for every item in the list, so if I have 30 items in the list and there is around 10 requests per second, do the math. @figs

Comment: Is there a reason why you are creating your own custom model rather than using something like `QStandardItemModel`? A `QStandardItem` object would automatically store the pixmap in memory, thus giving you the required caching. Typically I recommend using a builtin model rather than building your own, but perhaps you have a specific reason for doing so?

Comment: I don't think I have a good reason not to use `QStandardItemModel`. I used `QAbstractListModel`, because I followed a tutorial for creating `QListView` using models. I'll try using your suggestion, but first I'll try to implement simple caching in the model itself.@three_pineapples

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully optimized thumbnail loading by caching all the data in the model itself. Maybe it is not the best way to do this but it works really fast now. Here is what the model looks like now.

```
class GeneralAssetIconModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GeneralAssetIconModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._data = []
        self.cache = {}

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self._data)

    def data(self, index, role):
        index_row = index.row()
        if index_row in self.cache and 'DecorationRole' in self.cache[index_row] and 'DisplayRole' in self.cache[index_row]:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
                return self.cache[index_row]['DecorationRole']
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return self.cache[index_row]['DisplayRole']
        else:
            if index_row not in self.cache:
                self.cache[index_row] = {}
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
                taskModel = self._data[index_row]
                ext = taskModel.getData().obj['type']['ext']

                pix = QtGui.QPixmap(160, 160)
                pix.load('Assets/thumbnail-default.jpg')

                if ext == '.psd':
                    pix = PhotoshopHelper.getLatestThumbnail(taskModel)
                if ext == '.ai':
                    pix = IllustratorHelper.getLatestThumbnail(taskModel)
                if ext == '.mra':
                    pix = MariHelper.getLatestThumbnail(taskModel)
                if ext == '.indd':
                    pix = IndesignHelper.getLatestThumbnail(taskModel)
                if ext == '.ma':
                    pass

                self.cache[index_row]['DecorationRole'] = QtGui.QIcon(pix)
                return QtGui.QIcon(pix)
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                self.cache[index_row]['DisplayRole'] = self._data[index_row].getName()
                return self._data[index_row].getName()
```